# can't set absolute element from left to right after @media screen change

Tags: css

Cant move Absolute element from left to right after media screen change

```
#name {
position:absolute;
margin-top:9.8%;    
left:5%;
color:black;
font-family:futuraat;
font-size:2.2vw;    
z-index:100;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:760px){

#name {
font-size:4vw;
margin-top:16%;
right:5%;
}
}
```

I don't know why but it is not moving? Every other property is working except the position... Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the property *left: auto* to *#name* on media screen.

Comment: That TOTALLY worked. Can you ask you why It has to be done like that, because I don't see logic in the world of super logical CSS.  Thank you!

Comment: @ВалериК. When your element has absolute position it follows the property. You property "left" has already a value. So you need to reset the value "left" in order for the "right" to work.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!